# It is possible to use euca-register on AWS with a snapshot instead of an image location (manifest.xml)?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, eucalyptus

I have a snapshot that I would like to register as an AMI on Amazon Web Services. I can register this snapshot easily enough using ec2-tools' ec2-register but I would prefer to use euca2ools. I know euca2ools is constantly playing catch up, but I can see the option of snapshot in euca-register.

Is it possible to register an AMI from a snapshot with euca2ools?